Cookies not being saved in browser
I am using React and Express
I am sending cookies using res.cookie, which are being received by the browser, but they are not being saved in the browser.
This is my code for generating and sending the cookie
const jwtToken = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: user._id, email: user.email,
      },
      process.env.SECRET_KEY,
      {
        expiresIn: "1d",
      }
    );

    res.cookie("accessToken", jwtToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "None",
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      maxAge: 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      path: "/",
    });

This cookie is also available in the response headers for the login endpoint

However, when I use the verify endpoint, which has authenticate middleware to extract user from the accessToken, it is not receiving the "accessToken" cookie.
Under the application section, the accessToken cookie is not being saved.
This is my verify user request
const config = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_LINK}/auth/verify`,
      method: "get",
      withCredentials: true,
    };

I tried on localhost and on hosted platform as well, I don't understand what the issue is

Was the request in which the cookie was originally received, also a background request? And if so, did that also have withCredentials: true set?

@CBroe yes that was the issue with my code. Previously I had it, but I later commented it out because I thought I would not need cookies before logging in.
Once I uncommented that line, it worked!
Thanks!

It's very important that you use the relevant credentials options in ALL requests. One common pattern I see on Stack Overflow is forgetting to include it on the initial login request.
